# Temporarily disabling jshint option W098 does not work

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have the following snippet of code:

```
/* jshint -W098 */
/* jshint -W106 */
var pro6pp_auth_key = 'some key';
/* jshint +W106 */
```

However, I would like to re-enable option W098 afterwards. So my snippet would look like this:

```
/* jshint -W098 */
/* jshint -W106 */
var pro6pp_auth_key = 'some key';
/* jshint +W106 */
/* jshint +W098 */
```

This triggers the error

```
[L6:C20] W098: 'pro6pp_auth_key' is defined but never used.
```

For option W106 everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in jshint. It can be triggered with this input:

```
/* jshint -W098 */
var main = function (x) {
}
/* jshint +W098 */
```

jshint will report the following, despite W098 being turned off.

```
test.js: line 2, col 9, 'main' is defined but never used. (W098)
test.js: line 2, col 23, 'x' is defined but never used. (W098)
```

I dug a little into the jshint source but couldn't find the exact source of the error. It appears to be related to how [doFunction in src/jshint.js](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/2.x/src/jshint.js#L2936) restores the ignore array after processing a function.

There's an open issue for this bug ([1140](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1140)).